# Make ElseIf Statement Check Strings

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, my.settings

I would like to know, how to make `ElseIf` statement check if a string in a textbox equals to the string in `My.Settings.Something`?

Comment: `elsif My.Settings.Something = textbox.Text`

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically :

```
    If My.Settings.Something <> TextboxName.Text Then 
        // to do if...
    ElseIf My.Settings.Something = TextboxName.Text Then 
        // to do else if...
    ElseIf My.Settings.Something = 999 Then 
        // to do else if...
    Else
        // to do else... 
    End If
```

Depending on variable types you using in the settings you might need to use My.Settings.Something.ToString() instead of My.Settings.Something

Additionally, it might be needed to first store the variable from the textbox into a variable of the right type.

```
   Dim dblVar as Double
   dblVar = TextBoxName.Text
```